# Django admin dashboard, not able to "select all" records

Tags: python, django

I have a weird issue were I am not able to "select all" records for any model in my Django admin dashboard.

[image: Django admin, not able to "select all"]

**This is using Django 1.10.1**

It is a small issue, but I still rather have it solved. Appreciate any help!

Comment: What web browser do you use? can you try with different browsers?

Comment: your statics are not being delivered properly. Open the developer console and check for errors

Comment: @idik tried with chrome and firefox ,still the same issue (even in incognito mode)

Comment: @e4c5 no errors at all, it's weird

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bug. I believe it would be addressed in the later release.

Comment: Can you elaborate? A quick search didn't reveal any outstanding bugs that I saw.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post, but I just had the same problem. I ran

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

Then I cleared my cached images and files in chrome. This solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to run

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

so your js will function on the page.